# I am getting this error 'os.chdir(path) NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:' can someone explain why?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to define path and change directory so I can open an image but I'm getting this error:

```
os.chdir(path)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:
```

```py
path = r'C:\Users\marzo\Downloads\frogblood.jpg'
filepath2 = r'C:\Users\marzo\Downloads\fishblood.jpg'
filepath3 = r'C:\Users\marzo\Downloads\birdblood.jpg'
os.chdir(path)
imagename = 'frogblood'
image = imageio.imread(imagename + '.jpg')
img = rgb2gray(image)
img= gaussian(img, sigma=1)
#Show image
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Because `path` is a _file_, not a _directory_.

Comment: You don't need `chdir()` at all.  Just pass the full image path to `imread()`.  `path` is already the full path to the image file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change directory to a specific file, so you would need the path of the folder, not the file. Editing your code a little bit, here's what you'd want

```py
path = r'C:\Users\marzo\Downloads\frogblood.jpg'
filepath2 = r'C:\Users\marzo\Downloads\fishblood.jpg'
filepath3 = r'C:\Users\marzo\Downloads\birdblood.jpg'
os.chdir("\\".join(path.split("\\")[:-1])) // This removes anything after the last slash making it r"C:\Users\marzo\Downloads"
imagename = 'frogblood'
image = imageio.imread(imagename + '.jpg')
img = rgb2gray(image)
img= gaussian(img, sigma=1)
#Show image
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```